# Save and delete UIImages from UIImagePickerController using iOS file system

Tags: swift, filesystems, uiimagepickercontroller, local, swift5

I have a UICollectionView that uses a UIImagePicker. I want the filesystem to create a folder in "Documents" and save/delete the UIImages in it. The photoArray is currently what the UICollectionView uses to add new UIImages. ( I researched documentation for Apple file system but its difficult to grasp )

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var editBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var photoArray: [UIImage] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

// Button used to activate the UIImagePickerController
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        photoArray.append(pickedImage)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

// MARK: - collectionView DataSource
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photoArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.photoImageView.image = photoArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

I found this code online but I do not know what the "return documentDirectory[0]" outputs.

```
func documentDirectory() -> String {
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, 
.userDomainMask, true)
    return documentDirectory[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the string formed path, you can use it to save an image picked from a UIImagePickerController.

Save image

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)!
do {
  try data.write(to: URL(string: "\(self.documentDirectory())/nameImage")!, options: .atomic)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Get image

```
do {
   let readData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(self.documentDirectory())/nameImage")!)
   let retreivedImage = UIImage(data: readData)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Where do I insert the Save image and Get image methods? i tried the func imagePickerController() and func documentDirectory()

Comment: You can use save image in func imagePickerController() after you select an image. This image will be saved in the document on your phone. And use readImage from document in func viewDidLoad(), use "photoArray.append(retreivedImage)".
When you visit the app for the second time, the photos will automatically load.